# Background image en CakePhp 3

Tags: php, css, cakephp

Buenas!

Tengo un pequeño problemilla, que no entiendo por qué pasa!
El tema es que cada usuario de mi sistema puede seleccionar su fondo de pantalla, para ello hago esto :

1) en Layout/default.ctp ->

```
background: url('<?php echo "../img/fondos/".$current_user['fondo']?>') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Ahora eso funciona en algunas paginas de mi sistema, pero no en otras.
Eso es lo que no entiendo!!

Por ejemplo
En Controller/index (que en realidad se muestra Controller/)  o Controller/view/1 no funciona, 
en otras si.

Alguna solución?
Gracias!

Comment: Muy probable que sea la ruta que esta mal. Abre la consola y verifica si esta mostrando algun error y dinos cual es. Y tambien agrega a tu pregunta la estructuras de tus carpetas para poder dar una respuesta completa.

Comment: No uses rutas relativas para algo que se va a utilizar a diferentes niveles. Parece que la carpeta img está en el raíz, por eso cuando es /Controller/algo funciona (porque se sube un nivel al raíz y de ahí a img), mientras que falla para /Controller/subdirectorio/algo (porque se sube un nivel y no hay carpeta img en /Controller/). Prueba a usar /img/fondos/ (sin los ..) para ver si así funciona.

Answer (score 0):

En cake lo pude solucionar asi :

`background: url('<?php echo $this->Url->image('fondos'.DS.$fondo)?>'`)

El framework tiene Helpers que solucionan el enrutamiento, dejo información [acá](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html)

Saludos!